# Can you use range of ports in AWS network ALB? How?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elb, aws-nlb

Can you use range of ports like 12000 - 12100 in AWS network ALB? Clients should be able to connect on that port range. How?

Comment: range of ports for listener? for securiy groups? where?

Comment: Clients will be connecting on that range of ports.

Comment: do you mean by ephemeral ports? https://alliescomputing.com/knowledge-base/how-to-handle-ephemeral-ports-in-security-groups-and-network-acls#:~:text=On%20AWS%2C%20the%20ephemeral%20port,Load%20Balancers%20is%201024%2D65535.&text=If%20you%20initiate%20an%20HTTP,side%20between%201024%20and%2065535.

Comment: I suppose yes. Have you implemented something like this?

Comment: Please edit your question and be _very specific_ in explaining your architecture. For example, please explicitly state what ports you wish to use for what connection (inbound to Load Balancer, from LB to app, from app to LB, from LB back to calling client). We will then be in a better position to be able to answer your question.